# Add multiple values to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algorithm

I have a map terrain like this: http://ast-ss.se/terrain/

All the square's id's is in an array:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 160; i++)
{
    squares.push(''+i);
}
```

When I click on a square, I want to take the index position of that square, and put in an another array, this works fine:

```
   angular.element('.click').click(function() {


                    var squareId = angular.element(this).attr('id');                //Rutans id
                    var squareIndex = squares.indexOf(squareId);                    //Rutans index som vi klickar på
                    var squareFirstIndex = squares.indexOf('1');                    //Utgå ifrån den första             

                    interval.push(squareIndex);  //Add the index here
                    console.log(interval);
```

However, this solution only adds one to array, one for each click. The thing I want is to add the whole interval of the square's indexe's.

Example: When you are on a square with the index 2, and click on an square with an index of 6, I want to stor the interval between 2 and 6(3,4,5) in the array when you doing one click.

How can I do this?

Comment: try to use _array.concate_

`interval.concat([squareIndex])`

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan: That don't work. Concat is used to concat two arrays into one?

Comment: yes , may be Im understood wrong ? interval already array yes ? and you want to add another values of them or not ?

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan: I want to capture the interval between one square and another square, let's say 2..5, and in this case get the 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a range of an array with the `slice` method. This doesn't change the original array and returns a copy. The start index is includive, the end index is exclusive. If the start index is equal or greater than the end index, the resulting array is empty.

So:

```
var here = squares.indexOf(here_id);
var there = squares.indexOf(there_id);
var interval;

if (here < there) {
    interval = squares.slice(here + 1, there);
} else {
    interval = squares.slice(there + 1, here);
}

console.log(interval);
```